# Is it possible to use a variable by all the classes in a package?

Tags: android, variables

I wanted to use a variable's value in all the classes under a package. where should i declare the that variable?

Answer (score 2):

you can declare the variable in any class as static.

```
public class SomeClass {

  static Object yourVariable;

}
```

and access it from other classes:

```
public class OtherClass {

  public void method(){
    Object local = SomeClass.yourVariable;
  }

}
```

use no modifier (no public, no private) infront of the variable to make it package visible. [More about modifiers and visibility here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Comment: Just a precisation: this is true if you are acting under the same process. If you have two or more different process accessing this variable, they will have a different object for each different process (or VM).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't add a privacy modifier, variable is package private meaning it can be used by all classes within a same package. That solves your **question**.

Additionally, `static` modifier makes a variable usable from the class instead of object. There's only 1 possible instance of the variable for all objects of the class.

```
public class MyClass {

    //visible for all classes in the same package
    int variable;

    //same as above, but static
    static int variable;
}
```

Way to call if it's a **static** variable:

```
MyClass.variable
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a class which will have static variables.
Code below..

```
public class ConstantClass {

        static String strr = "Your value";
}
```

You can access this variable using

```
ConstantClass.strr = "Changed value";
```

in any of your class.

Comment: you should not use public for package visibility only.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to access a variable from anywhere in your application you have to use a **static** variable.

In a simple example you would declare your variable like this.

```
public class Example {
     public static string EXAMPLE_STRING = "example";
}
```

You then access the variable from anywhere you want via the Class like this:

```
Example.EXAMPLE_STRING
```

If you want to restrict access to one package remove the public keyword.

Comment: you should not use public for package visibility only.

Comment: That's what it say at the bottom :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shared Preferences class. This is example for using Shared Preferences

```
public static final String MyPreferences = "MyPrefs" ;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
Editor editor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPreferences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
}

//For Save Value (But the value is string)
public void saveValue(String code, String value) {
    editor.putString(code, value);
    //Dont forget this method must be typed, too... 
    editor.apply();
}

//For Get Value (But the value is string)
public String getValue(String code) {
    return sharedPreferences.getString(code, "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to override the application class and init the variable there. You can get your application from every activity with getApplication() and have access to your global variables. Do you need an example code?
The positive effect is that you dont have to deal with static stuff.

Answer (score -1):

You can declare it as *public static* variable in whatever class you wish. See [this link for a small explanation](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/java/java-for-beginners-static-variables-what-are-they.html).

Comment: you should not use public for package visibility only.